# EditText stops displaying characters as I type?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Basically what happens is I will start typing on the keyboard (stock and third party), and all of a sudden it stops showing characters I type in the EditText, (sometimes) resets the caret to the beginning, yet I know I'm still typing because the suggestions box shows the characters as I type.  I've experienced the behavior on at least 5 different devices as well as the emulator but can't seem to nail down a solution.

It is seemingly random; I'm not reading any error logs through DDMS from the system, so I'm a little baffled.

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsB49.png)

Here is the XML layout of the EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/etMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textAutoCorrect"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my code from the Activity:

```
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMain);

    et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                String sendText = v.getText().toString();

                if (sendText.length() > 0) {
                    v.setText("");

                    ....

                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Appreciate any insights on how to fix this issue. Let me know if you need anything else...

Thanks!

**EDIT:** It almost seems like the inputmethod is disconnecting from the EditText in the middle of an edit.  *Sometimes* I will get this warning when it happens: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(1035): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

Comment: This issue is under investigation by Google now... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17508

Answer (score 0):

Another developer (not me) may have found a workaround for this.  Check out [this comment](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17508#c6) on the defect report.

Comment: No kidding?  Well if it is in fact solved then I owe you big time.

Comment: It looks promising...I hope it's solved too, it was very annoying!

Comment: Any thoughts for a solution if we're not clearing the text? I'm having the same problem but at no point do I want to clear the text.